# Find union of two variable-name scalars

Tags: string, stata, local, stata-macros

I have a Stata program that outputs a local scalar of space-separated variable names.

I have to run the program twice on two samples (same `dta`) and store the union (intersection - variable names appearing in both scalars) as a new space-separated local scalar (for input to another program).

I can't figure out how to split (per spaces) and or test the occurrences of variable names in each.

Comment: Being local and being scalar are different. A scalar can have a temporary name, which is not the same thing. EIther way, showing your code as well as explaining it is a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stata has a bunch of extended macro functions to use on lists that you can find with `help macrolists`, where you can see that A & B returns the intersection of A and B.  If A="a b c d" and B="b c f g", then A & B = "b c".

This allows you to do something like this:

```
clear
scalar l1="vara varb varc"
scalar l2="varc vard vare"
local l1 = scalar(l1)
local l2 = scalar(l2)
local inter: list l1 & l2
scalar inter="`inter'"
scalar list inter
```

You convert the scalars to locals, get their union, and convert that into a  scalar. It is probably easier to just modify your code to use locals rather than scalars so you don't have to deal with conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I perfectly understand your question, if this is not the appropriate answer, please add an example for us to work with.

Here is the code that checks two space-separated macros and gets their intersection, even if it's not the most elegant, unless your macros are huge it should still be quite fast.

```
local list1 first list here
local list2 list two here
local intersection 

foreach l1 in `list1' {
    foreach l2 in `list2' {
        // if they overlap, add to the intersection macro
        if "`l1'" == "`l2'" {
            local intersection `intersection' `l1'
        }
    }
}

mac list // show the macros stored currently in the do file
```